# Can I plug French electronics into Russian sockets without an adaptor?

Tags: russia, power

According to [this](http://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plug-voltage-by-country/) page, Russian and French sockets/plugs are the same "shape", but in France we use 230 Volts while the Russians use 220 Volts. Will a laptop charger and other electronics work with Russian sockets?

Comment: Shape may be a problem still, while the overall look of the plug is the same, older Soviet sockets were used with thinner and smaller plugs. Be careful in old buildings with these things - it's possible to force your plug in, but very difficult to pull it out without tearing the socket apart.

Comment: I recently spent a month in Russia (all the way from east to west) with electronic devices from both the Netherlands and AU/NZ and had no issues charging or connecting those. Not sure where you're going, but I wouldn't expect any problems.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it should work.

Electricity supplies with nominal voltages of 220, 230 or 240 volts are *in practice* the same. There are tolerances of about ±10 % in the voltage (to account for the voltage drop in transmission lines which depends on the load), so devices labeled with either of these voltages will *actually* be designed to function on anywhere between 200 and 260 volts, give or take.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that today, things like laptop chargers are usually designed to run on everything. That is 100-240V 50-60Hz. Most of these devices have a label, so check what it says for "input".

Comment: And that is just the nominal range, IIRC there is a 10% margin either side of that, so the actual range is 90 to 264.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the socket delivers different voltage but electric appliances will support a range of voltages, and plug types C, E, F are compatible with the sockets.

See http://www.worldstandards.eu/electricity/plug-voltage-by-country/

Answer (score 3):

As I'm posting this from a French laptop plugged into a wall in a Moscow apartment, I can confirm that everything works perfectly without any need for adaptors.